# IndexError: list assignment index out of range in dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, terminal

I am doing a program to modify the profiles of the windows terminal, and these are in a JSON file. Well I want to put another profile using python (the profile is a dictionary) and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELLNEGRA\Desktop\wtedit.py", line 31, in <module>
    datos["profiles"][len(datos["profiles"])]["guid"] ="{"+pguid+"}"
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is this:

```
import json
import os
import secrets
import numpy as np

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

file = open(path+"/profiles.json","r")
contenido = file.read()
file.close()

datos = json.loads(contenido)

print("Tenes "+str(len(datos["profiles"]))+" consolas registradas.")

print("Añadiendo otra consola...")
pguid = secrets.token_hex(4)+"-"+secrets.token_hex(2)+"-"+secrets.token_hex(2)+"-"+secrets.token_hex(2)+"-"+secrets.token_hex(6)
print("Guid generado: "+pguid)
pname = input("Ingrese el nombre de la consola:")
proot = input("Ingrese la ruta de la consola:")
#datos["profiles"][len(datos["profiles"])] = dict() #Here the error appears
datos["profiles"][len(datos["profiles"])]["guid"] ="{"+pguid+"}"
datos["profiles"][len(datos["profiles"])]["name"] =pname
datos["profiles"][len(datos["profiles"])]["name"] =proot

dumpdatos = json.dumps(datos, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

file = open(path+"/profiles.json","w")
file.write(dumpdatos)
file.close()
```

How do I put the dictionary there without an error?

The profiles.json content:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
    "defaultProfile": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
    "keybindings": [],
    "profiles": [
        {
            "commandline": "powershell.exe",
            "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Windows PowerShell"
        },
        {
            "commandline": "cmd.exe",
            "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "CMD"
        },
        {
            "commandline": "C:\\Users\\DELLNEGRA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python.exe",
            "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6102}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Python"
        },
        {
            "guid": "{2c4de342-38b7-51cf-b940-2309a097f518}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Ubuntu",
            "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"
        },
        {
            "commandline": "c",
            "guid": "{e78a660a-660b-4d0e-2cc5-35707797c95e}",
            "name": "c"
        }
    ],
    "schemes": []
}
```

i tryed with `datos["profiles"][len(datos["profiles"])].append({"guid":"{"+pguid+"}","name":pname,"commandline":proot})` but dont works

Comment: How about changing `len(datos["profiles"])` to `len(datos["profiles"]) -1`?

Comment: Can you show was the data of `profiles.json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re trying to *add* a new entry to the end of a list, use `.append`:

```
datos["profiles"].append({'guid': ..., 'commandline': ..., 'name': ...})
```

Note that you can construct the whole object all at once in append instead of setting the values one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Python specifications *guarantee* that this will be a subscript out of range:

```
datos["profiles"][len(datos["profiles"])]
```

or, more simply

```
my_list[len(my_list)]
```

Python lists are 0-indexed.  For instance, if your list hase 5 elements, the legal indices are 0..4; there is no element `5`.

Instead, try

```
datos["profiles"][-1]
```

to get the last element.

Comment: I want to do is add a dictionary, not modify the last one.

Comment: How does that relate to my answer?  I showed you how to correct the failing line of code.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I wanted to do something else. What I wanted to do was add a dictionary that represents the profile, not see the last one. When trying to add a dictionary I was wrong, not when trying to get values from it. I already solved it thanks to nneonneo with append. Also thank you very much.